# I cant set the calendar for alarm

Tags: android, calendar, set, alarmmanager, alarm

I am trying to set alarm for my courses. I need to kick of alarm 1 hour before they start. So I just want

- get week of year
- look through the weeks (loop ...51,52)

  - look through the classes (loop ...n)

    - set the day of week for this class
    - set the hour of day one hour before this class
    - set the minute to 00
    - set alarm using this calendar instance
  - end of loop (classes)
  - set the week to one week from current week

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
for (int i = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR); i <= 52; i++) {
    for (Dersler d : dersProgrami) {
        alarm = new DersAlarmi(String.valueOf(d.getBaslangicS()) + "00", d.getDersAdi(), d.getDerslik());
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, d.getDayOfClass()+1);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, d.getStartHour());
        cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -1);
        Log.i("ALARM KURULDU",
            String.valueOf(i) + String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))+"."+String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH))+"."+String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR))+" "+String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY))+":"+String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE))+" Ders:" + d.getDersAdi()
                + " Hafta:"
                + cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) + " Gün:"
                + cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) + " Saat:"
                + cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        dersAlarmlari.add(alarm);
    }
    cal.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)+1);
}
```

Current date time is: 23.04.2012 23:37

Logcat is:

```
04-23 23:23:10.835: I/ALARM KURULDU(16380): 17 25.3.2012 14:0 Ders:DATA MINING Hafta:17 Gün:4 Saat:14

04-23 23:23:10.835: I/ALARM KURULDU(16380): 17 23.3.2012 8:0 Ders:Database Management and SQL Hafta:17 Gün:2 Saat:8

04-23 23:23:10.855: I/ALARM KURULDU(16380): 17 25.3.2012 12:0 Ders:ENTREPRENEURSHIP Hafta:17 Gün:4 Saat:12

04-23 23:23:10.865: I/ALARM KURULDU(16380): 1723.3.2012 11:0 Ders:GRADUATION PROJECT Hafta:17 Gün:2 Saat:11

04-23 23:23:10.865: I/ALARM KURULDU(16380): 18 25.3.2012 14:0 Ders:DATA MINING Hafta:17 Gün:4 Saat:14

04-23 23:23:10.885: I/ALARM KURULDU(16380): 18 23.3.2012 8:0 Ders:Database Management and SQL Hafta:17 Gün:2 Saat:8

04-23 23:23:10.885: I/ALARM KURULDU(16380): 18 25.3.2012 12:0 Ders:ENTREPRENEURSHIP Hafta:17 Gün:4 Saat:12

04-23 23:23:10.895: I/ALARM KURULDU(16380): 18 23.3.2012 11:0 Ders:GRADUATION PROJECT Hafta:17 Gün:2 Saat:11

04-23 23:23:10.905: I/ALARM KURULDU(16380): 19 25.3.2012 14:0 Ders:DATA MINING Hafta:17 Gün:4 Saat:14
```

...

So why does it say its 23.**03**.2012 or 25.**03**.2012 in the logcat instead of todays date 23.**04**.2012? I have been wasting my hours for this, can anybody tell me the right way to set the alarms please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using this to print the month: `cal.get(Calendar.MONTH))`

However the months returned look to be zero indexed.

According to the calendar manpage, the value of `JANUARY` is 0, and the value of `APRIL` is 3. Therefore if you want to print the month as would be typically printed (April = 4), then just add one to the month before printing.

Comment: String.valueOf((cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+1)) did not effect anything still prints 3 :S Anyway, what can you say for the day? And it seems i cant add 1 to the current week too...

Comment: Why are you adding to DAY_OF_MONTH? I'm referring to MONTH, not DAY_OF_MONTH

Comment: My mistake, ok thanks for the month but still got problem with day of month, and also it seems i cant iterate weeks with cal.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)+1)

Comment: Hmm, I don't understand what is wrong with WEEK_OF_YEAR line, it looks like it should work to me. Can you see what happens if you try cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1) instead? The doc said that 'add' forces an immediate recomputation instead of a delayed one, maybe theres a bug or something.

Comment: cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1); did the iteration. Alarms should be set now, its 24.04 now, next alarm seems its going to be triggered on 25.04 but there are alarms for 23.04. Shouldnot Android os have kicked those alarms immediately which are in past?